# displaying recently saved file in custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, displayobject

I am working on android app to make animated gif. In this app I want to display the created gif in custom view. I made 'DisplayGif' activity that when the gif is created and saved in sd card in 'myFile' folder, this activity display the recently saved. In the custom view I used this code to get the last gif:

```
String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath();

String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/myFile";

File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

File[] listFile = targetDirector.listFiles();

Arrays.sort( listFile, new Comparator()
{
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return +1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}); 

String s = listFile[0].getAbsolutePath();


mMovie = Movie.decodeFile(s);
```

This does not work but when I used "listFile[1].getAbsolutePath();" It worked for the previous saved gif not the new one! Is there a better way to display the newest gif?

Comment: are you using adapter..???

Comment: you want to get last saved gif file ?

Comment: Keep the ref of latest saved file and return it from class through get method

Answer (score 0):

you don't pay attention to ASC and DESC sort. you can find last item by `listfile[listfile.lentgh-1]` 
OR
you must use from 'reverseOrder'. make Comprator class like below:

```
public class ObjectComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

@Override
   public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
        return +1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    } if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
        return +1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

use this class in your code like this:

```
Comparator<Object> descendingObjectComparator = Collections.reverseOrder(new ObjectComparator());
```

and sort your array by this code:

```
  Arrays.sort(listFile , descendingObjectComparator);
```

if you want know more about arrays and sort, you can use [this link](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-arrays-examples-with-comparable-and-comparator)

Comment: thank you for answer. I tried the 'ObjectComparator' class, that reverse the array so I can get the oldest 'gif' file by using 'listFile[0]' here the custom view show the gif perfectly but when I use 'listFile[listFile.length-1]' to get the newest, the custom view does not display.

Comment: @majidjiji do you check the value of this item? is it fill and correct?

Comment: After I tried your code I got the the newest saved gif correctly, so when I press the 'next' button the gif is saved and then I go to the 'DisplayActivity' that has the custom view. Then the gif is not displayed, but when I recreate the activity "once or more" it is finally displayed!!

Comment: @majidjiji it is not a problem about your array and sort it. it seems, you need invalidate or other solution. you can ask your new question in other post.